# JavaScript use HTML Tags

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to ask how i can work with html tags e.g. `<h1>` or `<b>` in JavaScript?

My Code :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  if (window.location.href.indexOf("/login?from=") !== -1) { 
    var hint=document.createTextNode("<b>Hello</b>"); 
    var node = document.getElementById("main-panel"); 
    node.insertBefore(hint, node.firstChild); 
  }
})
```

But they show the text string `<b> hello </b>` and does not make it big .

i can only work in a js file i dont have the opportunities to work with div tags in html file

Comment: Because you insert it as text. Try innerHTML instead OR document.createElement("b") and appendChild

Answer (score 5):

First create an element `b` and the add the desired `text` to it.

```js
var bold = document.createElement('b')
bold.innerHTML = "hello"
var parent = document.getElementById("haha");
parent.appendChild(bold)
```

```html
<div id="haha">put the text here
</div>
```

Comment: The Problem i only have an js file and can work in the JS File i dont have an html file where i can paste the div tag.

Comment: @M.Max: Aren't you fetching the node from HTML here? : `var node = document.getElementById("main-panel");` you do have an element with `main-panel` id.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this script:

```
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("/login?from=") !== -1) { 
           var hint = '<b>Hello</b>';
           document.write(lines);
           var node = document.getElementById("main-panel"); 
           node.insertBefore(hint, node.firstChild); 
       }
       })   
       </script>
```

I tested and it worked.

Comment: How i can use this one in my example because if i change the line var hint=document to var lines they show me only the messsage and not the requested page

Comment: I change my answer above, please check.